# Is it okay to publish an iOS app that won't work without an iCloud account?

Tags: ios, icloud, appstore-approval

Does Apple frown upon apps that won't work without a valid iCloud account?

i.e. Can one use iCloud as the *only* authentication method in an iOS app that requires authentication?

Comment: It's not ideal, but you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently submitted an that does this and it was approved.  I used iCloud and CloudKit for authentication and server.  My initial viewController warns the user they must be logged into iCloud in order to use the app.